# Laravel validation rules - how optional, but only if another condition is true

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

How can I make a custom rule using Validation, so that the field can be nullable 'since' call function the result is true, otherwise, the field becomes required.

Of course I tried to use the 'nullable', but even if the field is empty, the Validation should execute the checkAreasDiff() function to validate that the field can be empty during the update.

In my controller, I created a function:

```
    private function validator_update(array $data) {

    \Validator::extend('areas_diff', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return checkAreasDiff();
    }, 'VALIDATOR AREAS_DIFF OK.');

    /**
     * RULES
     */
    $rules = [
        'fiscalizoarea'  => 'areas_diff',
    ];


    /**
     * Return \Validator
     */
    return \Validator::make($data, $rules, $msgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want one field to be required only if another is not null?

There is a Laravel rule for that already: [required_with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-with).

```
required_with:foo,bar,...
```

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any
>   of the other specified fields are present.

Or, if I'm getting your logic back to front: [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-without)

```
required_without:foo,bar,...
```

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any
>   of the other specified fields are not present.

Comment: You would still need `nullable`, so that if the rule decides it is not required, Laravel sets the field to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. After I posted my question, I had forgotten that when the form is submitted, as the field is empty, there is nothing for the `$request->all()` to display for my validator.

I do not know if this is the best solution, but I simply stored the `$request->all()` for an array variable, and I inform the variable to my validator:
`$formData['fiscalizoarea'] = $request->input('fiscalizoarea') ?: [];`

Comment: Could you update the question with all the fields, their types and the form field being used in the HTML?